# Using linq to remove a href tag inside cdata in xml file

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have following xml file:

```
<ab>
 <![CDATA[ 

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                     <th>abcdef</th>    
                           <th><a href="/1/2" target="_blank">Contact</a></th>          
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <p>
              <a href="/1/2" target="_blank">Home</a>
             </p>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 ]]>
</ab>
```

I am still learning linq. Want to know if there is an easier way to find all a href = "/1/2/" tags inside cdata and remove them. Like in above example it should just show Contact and Home and remove the

Comment: there is a large debate on using regex to parse html summed up by this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 uf you have a moment take a read its quite interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Main() 
{ 
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\test.xml");
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(doc.ToString());

    XNode node = xdoc.DescendantNodes().Single(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA);

    if (node.Parent != null)
    {
        string content = node.Parent.Value.Trim();
        IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
            XDocument.Parse(content).Descendants().Where(x =>
                                                             {
                                                                 XAttribute xAttribute = x.Attribute("href");
                                                                 return
                                                                     xAttribute !=
                                                                         null && xAttribute.Value == "/1/2";
                                                             });

        // do something here
    }
}
```

contents of test.xml is

```
<ab> 
 <![CDATA[  

    <table> 
        <tbody> 
            <tr> 
                <th>abcdef</th>     
                <th><a href="/1/2" target="_blank">Contact</a></th>           
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
             <p> 
              <a href="/1/2" target="_blank">Home</a> 
             </p> 
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
 ]]> 
</ab>
```

Comment: of course if whats in cdata is horridly formed its not going to load into xdocument, but in this case it isn't so it does :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think LINQ is the best way to go about this problem. Personally, I would use Regular Expression. Here is an example of how this could be done:

[Example: Scanning for HREFs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9e807fx.aspx)

In general, if you are doing any more intensive HTML processing, using an HTML parser is probably the best way to go, such as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Regex sample code:

```
Regex hrefRegex = new Regex(@"href=""([^""]*"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |   RegexOptions.Compiled);
string output = hrefRegex.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(m => string.Empty));
```

Hope this helps,

Ivan

Comment: I am not at all good with regular expressions. Can you please tell me how can i remove the a href tag for above problem using regex?

Comment: @NoviceMe the example provided by Ivan is pretty straightforward and is a good base to start researching your solution.

Comment: @Ivan - I dont need to look for all href i need to look for exactly href="/1/2". So is this correct way to do it? (@"href=""([^/1/2])"

Comment: href=""/1/2"" - here is a link to a great tool for working with regex so you can experiment http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: first of all i have to say that expresso is a great tool, if you want to use linq i've done what you want above.

Comment: Yeah, completely agree with krystan. Both approaches will work well and if that's all there is to the scenario I think both approaches will work equally well.